# Replace the div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When I add a new div I want that the old div should change its position and go to the side. When I add all the new four divs the old divs should be hidden.
Is it possible as I have a full news website and I want to apply this thing to all four pages?

First page:

[image: First page]

More pages:

[image: more pages]

2 pages have the same format and 1 has another format.

```js
$(".js-post").on("mouseover", function() {
  const mainSrc = $(".js-main").attr("src");
  const targetSrc = $(this).attr("src");

  $(".js-main").attr("src", targetSrc);
  $(this).attr("src", mainSrc);
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.main-view {
  width: 70px;
  height: 500px;
  margin-right: 30rem;
  object-fit: cover;
}

img.main.js-main {
  width: 500px;
  object-fit: cover;
  height: 400px;
}

.thumbnail-view {
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: auto;
}

.post {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

.box {
  background: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box .imgBx {
  width: 150px;
}

* {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.hey {
  display: flex;
  width: 70%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 180px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.card {
  width: 280px;
  height: 260px;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  background: grey;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: flex-end;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.card:hover {
  transform: translateY(20px);
}

.card:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 176, 155, 0.5), rgba(150, 201, 61, 1));
  z-index: 2;
  transition: 0.5s all;
  opacity: 0;
}

.card:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.card .info {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(30px);
  transition: 0.5s all;
}

.card .info h1 {
  padding-top: 25px;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.card .info .btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  background: rgb(70, 218, 203);
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

.card:hover .info {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(0px);
}

.footer {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: rgb(70, 218, 203);
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 2px 0px 5px 0px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: auto;
  clear: both;
}

.on {
  width: 70px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 170px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  position: absolute;
}

.on p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!-- jQuery dependency -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- Body -->
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="main-view">
    <div>heading</div>
    <img class="main js-main" src="{% static 'images/banner/pic9.jpg' %}" width="300px" height="100" alt="yoga">
  </div>
  <div class="thumbnail-view">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="imgBx">
        <img class="post js-post" src="{% static 'images/banner/pic1.jpg' %}" height="100" alt="handshake">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="imgBx">
        <img class="post js-post" src="{% static 'images/banner/pic5.jpg' %}" width="300px" height="100" alt="peoplejoined">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="imgBx">
        <img class="post js-post" src="{% static 'images/banner/pic8.jpg' %}" width="300px" height="100" alt="peoplejoined">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="imgBx">
        <img class="post js-post" src="{% static 'images/banner/pic7.png' %}" width="300px" height="100" alt="peoplejoined">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="on">
  <p> Must Read </p>
</div>
<div class="hey">

  <div class="card">
    <img src="{% static 'images/banner/m.PNG' %}">
    <div class="info">
      <h1>US's Miami Fashion </h1>

      <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="{% static 'images/banner/c.PNG' %}">
    <div class="info">
      <h1>Muted demand for cotton </h1>

      <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img src="{% static 'images/banner/ss.jpg' %}">
    <div class="info">
      <h1>Srilanka garment export </h1>

      <a href="#" class="btn">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I'm understanding what you're asking for but here's my attempt anyway:

Assuming that this is all done using JavaScript, I would have all 5 items (the main one + 4 on the side) all in the same parent container and all using the same classes and use CSS (first-child/nth-child) rules for making the first one larger.

When adding a new item, you can use jQuery's .prepend() (see https://api.jquery.com/prepend/) to add it to the start of the parent container and then either use CSS to hide everything after the 5th item or use jQuery's .remove() (see https://api.jquery.com/remove/) to strip out the last item from the parent container if you actually want them removed.

Comment: how to use both prepend and remove thing together?

Comment: I am unable to prepend image in the same div